# KeyError: 'source' for from_pandas_edge_list()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, networkx, clique-problem

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.read_excel(r"/path/to/file.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet4")
df.edge=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,source='Abrev')
print(list(enumerate_all_cliques(nx.Graph(df.edge))))
```

if gives me a key error of `KeyError: 'Abrev'` for this code but I also tried changing `'Abrev'` to `0` and deleting the `source='Abrev'` all together and just get a slight different error for each; `'KeyError: 0` `'KeyError: 'source'`

Sample contents of excel file;

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | A | B | C | D |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| C | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| D | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: which columns do you have in the excel file? You may are simply looking for [`nx.from_pandas_adjacency`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_adjacency.html)?

Answer (score 0):

just add the `nx.from_pandas_adjacency`and you forgot a `nx.` in front of the `enumerate_all_cliques`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel(r"/path/to/file.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet4",index_col=0,usecols = "A:E")
df.edge=nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df)
print(list(nx.enumerate_all_cliques(nx.Graph(df.edge))))
```